# Java script Regex for mobile number vaidation (convert from PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Can somebody help me with converting a php regex to javascript regex?

It would be great and I would be appreciate you if you can help me, because I'm not so strong in regex.

```
preg_match('/^(((\+|00|۰۰)98|۹۸)|[0۰])?[9۹][01239۰۱۲۳۹]\d{8}$/u', $phone) == 0 )
```

This code is executed very well in PHP but not working in JavaScript
I search and research long time but i never find any useful answer.

please help to convert this php regex to javascript regex. . . 
thanks a lot

Comment: Are you looking for the regex in Java or Javascript? Your question and its tags are not really clear...

Comment: sorry . It was my mistake that The "script" is embedded in the body of question . 
Of course, this is because I'm not fluent in English and And have used Google Translate.
The question's text was amended . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, someone here did not help. I had read several articles about regular expressions And luckily I could solve my problem .
and Answer the question is:

```
^(((\+|(00)|(۰۰))(98)|(۹۸)|[0۰]))[9۹][01239۰۱۲۳۹]\d{8}$
```

The answer may be useful for those who have the same problem lead . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(((\+|00|۰۰)98|۹۸)|[0۰])?[9۹][01239۰۱۲۳۹]\d{8}$/u.test(phone)
```

Comment: Java or javascript？

Comment: sorry . java script code. I edit my request question too.